# Why new documents in mongo have an object and not an ObjectId?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

When inserting new documents in mongodb, ids don't look like ObjectId and instead they look like an object.

```
"_id" : {
        "_bsontype" : "ObjectID",
        "id" : "U\u0013[-Ð¤~\u001d$©t",
        "generationTime" : 1.43439e+09
}
```

Expected type:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("55107edd8e21f20000fd79a6")
```

My mongodb version is 3.0.3 and this is pretty much the code and the schema

```
var Script = {
    run: function() {
        return CourseModel.findQ()
        .then(function(courses){
            return courses.map(worker);
        }).catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
};

function worker(course){
    var category = { name: course.name, displayOrder: 0 };
        return CategoryModel.createQ(category).then(function() {
            course.set('name', undefined);
            return course.saveQ();
        });
}
module.exports = Script;

var CategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    displayOrder: Number,
    updateDate: Date,
    subcategories: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'subcategories'
    }]
});
```

Comment: does the data in the document also look like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The malformed ObjectIds are caused by a conflict with the mongoose version that mongoose-q is using. You'll need to update to mongoose-q to version 0.1.0. I was using 0.0.17 previously and saw exactly the same behavior that you saw here.

Answer (score 2):

That *is* what an ObjectID is. It is simply an object that contains those properties.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:
>
> - a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> - a 3-byte machine identifier,
> - a 2-byte process id, and
> - a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

```
{
    "_bsontype" : "ObjectID",
    "id" : "U\u0013[-Ð¤~\u001d$©t",
    "generationTime" : 1.43439e+09
}
```

`U\u0013[-Ð¤~\u001d$©t` is the 12 character **binary** string which gets converted to the familiar 24 char hex string (`55107edd8e21f20000fd79a6`) when the object as a whole is represented as a text value (i.e. its [`.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) function is invoked)

In Mongoose the documents also have a `.id` getter which give you the 24 char hex as a string value.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue here: [ObjectID not storing hexadecimal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897147/objectid-not-storing-hexadecimal-value)

It's definitely an issue with environments and something strange with the brew installation of MongoDB. I found that uninstalling from brew and reinstalling manually solved my issue. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

While I didn't figure out from a code/technical standpoint why it is returning the 12-byt BSON ObjectID rather than the Hexadecimal ObjectID... uninstalling MongoDB from brew and reinstalling it manually solved the issue.