# Returned Mongoose id different format than MongoDB shell results?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Clearly there is something I'm not understanding here. I perform a `Model.findOne()` query, followed by a `Model.find()` query based on the `findOne()` result.

The document IDs from the `Model.find()` query look like they're in a different format than when I query the same documents directly from the Mongo shell. I've Googled for an hour, but no luck. What am I missing??

**`Model.find()` results...**

```
{ _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'W_?àÅÜY¼-íbO' }, // <- Problem
  salt: 'ULRtWgj0qgblPRbSPwTe4A==',
  displayName: 'test tester',
  provider: 'local',
  username: 'tester',
  created: Tue Jun 14 2016 06:36:48 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time),
  roles: [ 'user' ],
  profileImageURL: 'modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png',
  referrers: { level1: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'W^_ó 5IE\u0013
    N\u0010c' } }, // <- Also problem
  password: 'jXpp+RJIegHFKD50sL2aOlOUhE0rvYtSJZIDB244SDIw93yrbuFCTUJK3SZIs3F
    w0DdHOUzlQoLQwTGEcF67Kg==',
  email: 'test@example.com',
  lastName: 'tester',
  firstName: 'test',
  __v: 0 
}
```

**Mongo Shell Results**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575f89e0c5dc59bc2ded62d5"), // <- This is different!
    "salt" : "ULRtWgj0qgblPRbSPwTe4A==",
    "displayName" : "test tester",
    "provider" : "local",
    "username" : "tester",
    "created" : ISODate("2016-06-14T04:36:48.130Z"),
    "roles" : [
            "user"
    ],
    "profileImageURL" : "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png",
    "referrers" : {
            "level1" : ObjectId("575ebef32035ccc8134e1063") // <- This too!
    },
    "password" : "jXpp+RJIegHFKD50sL2aOlOUhE0rvYtSJZIDB244SDIw93yrbuFCTUJK3S
      ZIs3Fw0DdHOUzlQoLQwTGEcF67Kg==",
    "email" : "test@example.com",
    "lastName" : "tester",
    "firstName" : "test",
    "__v" : 0
}
>
```

Can anyone explain to me what concept I'm missing? Most of my find queries are just fine...this is the first time I've encountered this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which versions of MongoDB and Mongoose are you using? It might be a version mismatch (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852106/why-new-documents-in-mongo-have-an-object-and-not-an-objectid/30855254) and some of its answers)

Comment: Good question. Looks like MongoDB version is 3.0.5, Mongoose version is 4.4.8, from the looks of things. According to this page, those versions should be compatible: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html

Comment: I regularly use very similar versions, and never ran into the problem you're describing. It might be worth trying the latest Mongoose (4.5.0), and/or do a full reinstall of all your dependencies (remove `./node_modules` and run `npm install`) to rule out any potential issues there.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm quite to that point yet - all of my other queries across the whole app work just fine. What's really confusing me is that Mongo shell simply has `ObjectId("xxxxx")`, but Mongoose returns a json object, `{ _bsontype: 'ObjectId', id: 'xxxxx' }`. Is that normal? i don't recall seeing that difference before.

Comment: I just realized my other functions also return results with similar id format, but it's still able to match the ids correctly. Not sure what's happening, but it's really confusing me.

Comment: No, it's not normal. The post I linked to in my first comment, and also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897147/objectid-not-storing-hexadecimal-value) suggest that it may be a version conflict.

Comment: Well, I've tried upgrading Mongo to the latest stable build (3.2.7), and also downgrading to 2.6.12 (my mongodb npm module says it expects `mongodb@>=2.0.39 <3.0.0`). However, I'm still seeing the same results. I also tried creating a new user with Mongo 2.6.12, and the format still comes out looking like all of the others. Completely boggled at this point.

Comment: Did you also reinstall all your dependencies?

Comment: Yeah, so unless I just screwed something up along the way, it's still giving me the same results.

Comment: Did you use `mongoimport` to import the data into MongoDB?

Comment: No - I haven't used `mongoimport` for anything. Btw, huge thanks for the help with this. Super frustrating at this point.

Comment: Yeah I can imagine that it is. What happens if you log `doc.toJSON()` on a document that's being shown incorrectly?

Comment: @robertklep I found a solution that works (below) again - huge thank you for the help. Still no idea what the root issue is, but this is working for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is going to sound really stupid, but in my `Mongoose.find()` results, instead of getting the id with something like `results.id` or `results._id`, I got it to match the strangely formatted id with `results._id.id` (since the `_id` itself is an object with an id value).

Seems hacky to me, but it works. So now I have something like:

```
id = results._id.id || results.id;
```

Seems super weird, but it works.

Comment: As a final attempt to get to the bottom of this (famous last words...), can you try this: `mongoexport -d DB -c COLLECTION --limit 10`. This should export 10 records of your collection in JSON format. In my case, ObjectId's look like this: `"_id":{"$oid":"..."}`. I wonder if it's the same for your database.

Comment: You may also have good results by calling `.toObject()` on a returned result too.

Comment: @robertklep here's the result for that user: `{"_id":{"$oid":"575f89e0c5dc59bc2ded62d5"},"salt":"ULRtWgj0qgblPRbSPwTe4A==","di
splayName":"test tester","provider":"local","username":"tester","created":{"$dat
e":"2016-06-14T04:36:48.130Z"},"roles":["user"],"profileImageURL":"modules/users
/client/img/profile/default.png","referrers":{"level1":{"$oid":"575ebef32035ccc8
134e1063"}},"password":"jXpp+RJIegHFKD50sL2aOlOUhE0rvYtSJZIDB244SDIw93yrbuFCTUJK
3SZIs3Fw0DdHOUzlQoLQwTGEcF67Kg==","email":"test@example.com","lastName":"test
er","firstName":"test","__v":0}`.

Comment: @slugonamission thanks for the suggestion - it's a great idea, but didn't help in my situation, unfortunately.

Comment: @aikorei yeah that looks similar to what I'm getting, so I'm officially out of ideas :(